How to determine the fill color at specific coordinates on the Turtle canvas?
I'm trying to create a function that will return the fill color at specified coordinates on the Turtle canvas. I've used the find_overlapping method from the turtle library to find objects on the canvas, but this method doesn't always return the desired results.
Here's my current method:
from turtle import *

def get_pixel_color(x, y):
    y = -y
    canvas = getcanvas()
    ids = canvas.find_overlapping(x, y, x, y)
    if ids:
        index = ids[-1]
        color = canvas.itemcget(index, "fill")
        if color:
            return color
    return "white"


However, this method sometimes returns "white" even when there is fill at the specified coordinates on the canvas. How can I correctly determine the fill color at specific coordinates on the Turtle canvas?
An example of my code
from turtle import *

def get_pixel_color(x, y):
    y = -y
    canvas = getcanvas()
    ids = canvas.find_overlapping(x, y, x, y)
    print(ids)
    if ids:
        index = ids[-1]
        color = canvas.itemcget(index, "fill")
        print(canvas.itemcget(index, "fill"))
        if color:
            return color
    return "white"

def frange(start, stop, step):
    while start <= stop:
        yield start
        start += step
        
SIZE = 40
tracer(0)
screensize(14000, 14000)
color('red')
position = pos()
left(90)
color('yellow')
begin_fill() 

for i in range(5):
    fd(9 * SIZE)
    rt(120)

end_fill()

color('red')
up()
setpos(position)
rt(120)
down()
for i in range(5):
    fd(9 * SIZE)
    rt(120)

up()
update()
c = 0

for x in range(-5, 10):
    for y in range(-5, 13):
        real_x, real_y = x * SIZE, y * SIZE
        print(get_pixel_color(real_x, real_y), pencolor())
        if get_pixel_color(real_x, real_y) == 'yellow':
            setpos(real_x, real_y)
            dot(5, 'blue')
            continue
            

done()

Any help would be appreciated!

The problem is that, if I fill a drawn shape with a color, this method can't determine what color it is at those coordinates. For instance, I filled a triangle with yellow, but when I tried to get the color at the coordinates inside the triangle, it gave me white instead of yellow.

How do you get the coordinates?  As I said in last comment, if the canvas is scrolled, the coordinates may not be the real coordinates.

I'm just going through a loop for x and y

Most of these variables aren't defined. Please share a [mcve] and explain what you're really trying to achieve with this function. Some sort of collision detection? There may be a cleaner/easier way to do whatever you think you need this function for--provide context.

The turtle draws a closed polygon with a fill of some color. Next, she puts points in integer coordinates all over the canvas, but I need these points to be placed only inside the shape, that is, in pixels with the fill color.

It is hard to identify the cause of the issue without a [mre].

I added a minimal reproducible example.

If you want to draw a triangle, you should use range(3) instead of range(5) in the first two for loops.  Also it is not clear how you verify that the function returns wrong color.

I see how the turtle moves along the coordinates and write the color to the console, which the function returns when the turtle on the yellow fill color is written white to the console. although the red color is detected perfectly .

I cannot get a yellow filled triangle by running your code, just a red outlined triangle.  However, if I change range(5) to range(3) as mentioned in my past comment, I can get a filled yellow triangle and a outlined red triangle.  The returned colors on those coordinates are correct by showing different color dots based on returned color.  Here is the result screenshot.

I am drawing a shape as it is written in the task, and I need to count the number of points inside the shape with integer coordinates, but my color detection method, for some reason, does not read the yellow fill color.

@sirniki : sorry ... can't reproduce the issue. The code (after correction of the loop, so that the filling actually takes place) you have provided creates points only within the area of the yellow triangle.

I have mentioned this issue twice in my past comment, but OP seems not aware of this.

@acw1668 : the OP involvement level shows that it had been probably not worth the time to provide support. Nothing unusual ... but discouraging for the responders a biit anyway. You need to go over it as smooth and fast as possible ... By the way: closing such question with so obvious answer and clear description of the issue is discouraging for the OP ... A loose-loose case ...
